# pg 7.18.0 in node js not working, throwing: Implicit disabling of certificate verification is deprecated and will be removed in pg 8

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rds, pg

I have a nodejs app with express that connects  with [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) to a database in RDS on AWS. The connection to the database is done with the following database url:

```
postgres://user:pasword@host.amazonaws.com:port/database?ssl=true
```

After the new release of pg version 7.18.0, our server failed to connect to the database throwing the following error:

```
error: unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5679: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
at Connection.parseE (/var/app/current/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:624:13)
at Connection.parseMessage (/var/app/current/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:423:19)
at TLSSocket. (/var/app/current/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:139:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)

DeprecationWarning: Implicit disabling of certificate verification is 
deprecated and will be removed in pg 8. Specify rejectUnauthorized: true to 
require a valid CA or rejectUnauthorized: false to explicitly opt out of MITM 
protection.
```

If I remove the "ssl=true" part from the database url it works, but that would mean there connection is not secure, right?

If I go back to use the 7.17.x version my problem is fixed, however I would like to understand if i am connecting to the database correctly? Should I add more parameters to the database url? I am missing something else or is it an issue with pg?

I opened up an [issue on github, link to the issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2089)

Comment: The bug was with pg itself, they fixed it in 17.18.1 However the DeprecationWarning is still being showed. Is the database url wrongly structured?

Comment: @Laurenze Albe I don't think is a duplicate of psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5679: server supports 2.0 to 3.0 . Even though the error is the same the issue in this one is a bug with pg itself that had been handled in release 7.18.1.